# Inject Inherited Class Instead of Base Class

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, ninject, dbcontext

I have the following set up:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<System.Data.Entity.DbContext>().To<OdyDb_Context>();
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>();
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<>)).To(typeof(UserStore<>)).;
}
```

The problem is that `UserStore` is being injected with `DbContext` instead of the required `ApplicationDbContext`.
How do I force it to use `ApplicationDbContext` instead?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(UserStore<>))
```